# ConcurrentHashMap contains Map Objects

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrenthashmap

If `ConcurrentHashMap` contains Map then, is Internal Values Map also behave Concurrent or not?
The following is my map object

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>> applicationDataMap = 
    new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Comment: Only if it is Concurrent too.

Comment: For sure no, expect it isa concurrent map also

Answer (score 1):

The variable declaration here only uses the `Map` interface. You can add any `Map` to this, whether concurrent or not. If you require all of the contained maps to be concurrent, you must declare them as such:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>>> applicationDataMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put any type of `Map` in `applicationDataMap`.

E.g.:

```
Map<String, String> innerInnerMap = new TreeMap<>();
Map<String, Map<String, String>> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
innerMap.put("innerKey", innerInnerMap);
applicationDataMap.put("key", innerMap);
```

There's nothing protecting these inner maps from being concurrently accessed by more than one thread. If you want to ensure their validity, you'd have to handle it explicitly.